# How do I correct an Empty DataFrame when filtering a a csv or excel file using into multiple files when using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have the following code it works and places the individual files in the output folder but all files are empty. I printed the filter1 and filter2 data frames and they both return empty Dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os


df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Path_to_file.csv", encoding= 'unicode_escape')
output_folder = r"C:\Output_folder"

filter1 = df.loc[(df['Type Of Offer'].str.strip()=='BIG') & (df['Offer Region'].str.strip()=='United States') & (df['Offer Brand'].str.strip()=='PLACEHOLDER') & 
   (df['Start Date'].str.strip()=='8/1/2023') & (df['End Date'].str.strip()=='8/1/2023'), ['Type Of Offer', 'Print Code', 'Offer Category', 'English Title', 'Discount Amount', 'Discount Currency', 'Offer Region', 'Offer Brand', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'SKU', 'Description', 'Stock Class Code']]
                 
filter2 = df.loc[(df['Type Of Offer'].str.strip()=='SMALL') & (df['Offer Region'].str.strip()=='United States') & (df['Offer Brand'].str.strip()=='PLACEHOLDER2') & 
   (df['Start Date'].str.strip()=='8/1/2023') & (df['End Date'].str.strip()=='8/1/2023'), ['Type Of Offer', 'Print Code', 'Offer Category', 'English Title', 'Discount Amount', 'Discount Currency', 'Offer Region', 'Offer Brand', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'SKU', 'Description', 'Stock Class Code']]

offer1_df = df[filter1]
offer2_df = df[filter2]

offer1_file = os.path.join(output_folder, 'offer1.csv')
offer2_file = os.path.join(output_folder, 'offer2.csv')

if os.path.exists(offer1_file):
    os.remove(offer1_file)

if os.path.exists(offer2_file):
    os.remove(offer2_file)

offer1_df.to_csv(offer1_file, index=False)
offer2_file.to_csv(offer2_file, index=False)
```

I get this output:

"Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Type Of Offer, Print Code, Offer Category, English Title, Discount Amount, Discount Currency, Offer Region, Offer Brand, Start Date, End Date, SKU, Description, Stock Class Code]
Index: []"

How can I ensure the filtered values appear? I am using Jupyter notebook

Comment: It is returning 0 for everything. The syntax and text match the file verbatim and matches in terms of capitalization and everything. Is there any other way to apply this filter?

Comment: `&` is a bit-wise _and_ operation.  I believe you probably want `and`, the logical operation.

Comment: @some3128 I got it working! I restarted and filtered out one condition at a time, it was the date formatting. I had to adjust it before the filters.